# Python 3.5 Selenium Webdriver IE

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I got a problem with IE webdriver, if I open a page I can find everything in that page but if I move from a page to another with different URL, when I try to search some element I receive every time the same error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to
>   get browser

My code is very simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml')
driver.get("http://www.virgilio.it/")#example
time.sleep(2)
print(driver.current_url)
```

The main problem is that fail just with IE webdriver but it's working with the Firefox and Chrome webdriver.

Some help Please!?!?!?!

Comment: What versions of IE and Windows?

Comment: IE 11.0.96, but I have automatic update of IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [InternetExplorerDriver wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) at SeleniumHQ is relevant here:

> For **IE 11** only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target
>   computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
>   of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the
>   key you must examine in the registry editor is
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. For 64-bit Windows
>   installations, the key is
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. Please note that the
>   `FEATURE_BFCACHE` subkey may or may not be present, and should be
>   created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
>   `DWORD` value named `iexplore.exe` with the value of `0`.

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks so so much in advance. Sorry to annoing you but do you know how can I introduce a Key in the registry? :D Thanks so so much

Comment: Just found how to do ;) Thanks so much :D

Comment: If you have 64-bit windows installations, make sure you also add registry as that is mentioned for 32-bit windows installations above. Means you have to follow procedure for 64-bit and also 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

To created commands from @Steven's answer. Just run these as Administrator:

```
REG Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE" /v "iexplore.exe" /t REG_DWORD 0
REG Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE" /v "iexplore.exe" /t REG_DWORD 0
```